# My App missing from Android Studio AVD Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, emulation

The app i runned there is no application for my application i just created

[image]

Attached is the photo of my emulator that it only have cordova apllication

i have created my app but i cant find a button to open my application in avd emulator in andriod studio

i have download cordova before but i have not used it to develop my application this times. I dont know how to run and open my appliaction i just created

This is my mainefest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fyp.user.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".photoplayer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: but you have run your app or have you just opened the emulator? You have to run the project.

Comment: i have run my app and it succesfully build

Comment: but i cant find a icon to run my app

Comment: post your manifest. You need the "launcher" intent filter

Comment: sometimes
it will show unforunately launcher 3 has stopped

Comment: did you "run" your app from Android Studio? The green triangle next to "app" on the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

try  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" remove ic_lanucher  from mipmap.
or just put another png in  @mipmap then try  android:icon="@mipmap/